# Coherent states of Fermi Operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, grassmann-numbers, quantum-statistics, coherent-states

I am currently following the book of Lowell.S.Brown.
In the book, we construct:
$$|\zeta\rangle = e^{\alpha^{\dagger} \zeta} |0\rangle \tag{2.4.38}$$
Now, to show that the states so constructed are coherent states, we apply the destruction operator to it:
$$\alpha |\zeta\rangle =\alpha e^{\alpha^{\dagger} \zeta} |0\rangle =e^{\alpha^{\dagger} \zeta} \zeta |0\rangle \tag{2.4.39}$$

But now, since $\zeta$ is a linear sum of operators $\xi_i' = \epsilon_i \xi_3$, $\epsilon_k$ being elements of grassmann algebra, we can write $\zeta = \xi_3 \zeta' \tag{2.4.40}$
Using the above relation and the fact that $\xi_3|0\rangle = [\alpha,\alpha^\dagger]|0\rangle = |0\rangle$, we get:
$$\alpha |\zeta\rangle = \zeta'|\zeta\rangle \tag{a} $$
where $\alpha$ and $\zeta'$ are operators. But the book has the eqn:
$$\alpha |\zeta\rangle = |\zeta\rangle \zeta' \tag{2.4.43}$$
meaning that the coherent state is an eigen state of the $\zeta'$ operator. I don't understand how to get from eqn(a) to eqn(2.4.43).